# Specifying a property DataType – using SHACL, rdfs:range or custom property?

Tags: rdf, ontology, wikidata, rdfs, shacl

I have an ontology like the below, with classes and literals:

```json
thing
    artist
    album
    playlist

literal
    literal_coordinate
    literal_integer
    literal_json
    literal_string
```

When introducing new properties, I want to ensure that the properties use a particular "data type" (similar to: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Data_type) so that the user interface can display the right type of entry or display format: AutoComplete for objects, Number for literal_integer, Map for literal_coordinate and so forth.

My understanding is that rdfs:range (or the less strict "schema:rangeIncludes") can be used to get a broad sense of the expected values in the object position of the triple statement.

Furthermore, there are SHACL shape constraints of the types sh:datatype, sh:nodeKind and sh:class that can constrain the expected values (https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/#core-components-value-type).

**Question**

**Which method would be strategic to specify the expected DataType of each property in a global fashion?** "range" seems too open-world oriented to rely on for this use case and I am not sure if SHACL was intended for such "global information" or if it primarily deals with validation of subsets of the graph? It seems Wikibase/Wikidata use a "flat DataType setup" as compared to a more elaborate object/literal hierarchy:

````
```json
datatypes
    Item (object relation)
    Media
    Mathematical expression
    etc.
```
````

The solution should ideally also take into consideration the notion of particular metadata around a data type such as "External identifier" (see Wikidata link for more information). This data type tells the system that to use additional information from the property to format the value:

```
    Data type
    {libraryOfCongressId} {dataType} {externalID} 

    Formatting options
    {libraryOfCongressId} {formatterURL} "https://id.loc.gov/authorities/$1"

    Property constraints
    {libraryOfCongressId} {formatConstraint} "(|((n|nb|nr|no|ns|sh|gf)([4-9])"
```

So, starting out a new ontology with similar use cases, is this a good blueprint for identifying and formatting External identifiers, or are there more adequate solutions?

Comment: Strictly speaking, rdfs:range is not necessarily "open world oriented", see https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_domainrange: *"Different applications will use this information in different ways. For example, data checking tools might use this to help discover errors in some data set, an interactive editor might suggest appropriate values..."*.

Comment: Thank you @StanislavKralin. OK, that was in part news to me, so thank you for filling more knowledge gaps! Still, it feels like we're trying to misuse rdfs:range for something it wasn't intended for. It would be interesting to understand how other KG applications have dealt with these more practical matters like DataTypes. I don't see much in terms of range/domain when looking at wikidata (but I may be mistaken) and schema.org adopted a slightly different approach. Case studies on representing literals/data types and linking them to properties (for applied purposes) would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find my answer satisfactory?

Answer (score 1):

RDF by itself does not impose any validity constraints on the triples in any graph. This is aided by the fact that RDFS is additive in nature:

```
ex:prop rdfs:range xsd:integer .

ex:resource ex:prop "abc" .
```

When equipped with a reasoner (for a particular ontology), this implies `"abc" a xsd:integer`. A reasoner may be used to detect contradictions; for example if it knows the complete set of `xsd:integer` instances, it may detect that `"abc"` is not one of them, and the graph would be contradictory then. However, if one only seeks to infer additional statements from a graph, a consistency check is not required (although a logician would argue that anything could be inferred from a contradictory statement).

Your description of the problem seems more focused on inference rather than validation, but I think `rdfs:range` is suitable for both cases. I will also stick to RDFS for now since that is understood the most. Note also that `schema:rangeIncludes` does not actually provide anything useful for any sort of inference (but it may be useful for producers of the data).

```
ex:authorityURL a rdfs:Datatype ;
  rdfs:subClassOf xsd:anyURI .

ex:formatterURL rdfs:range ex:authorityURL .
```

Already we have stated that any object linked with `ex:formatterURL` should be treated as `ex:authorityURL` and be a valid URI. Since `ex:authorityURL` is now a node in the graph, you can link any additional metadata to it for all tools you use.

```
ex:authorityURL schema:valuePattern "https:\\/\\/id\\.loc\\.gov\\/authorities\\/.+" .
```

Now you know what to put into the HTML `pattern` attribute.

When producing the data, you don't need to explicitly add the datatype to the literal (since it can be inferred), but it may be useful for tools that are good at datatype checking but not at inference:

```
ex:library1 ex:formatterURL "https://id.loc.gov/authorities/1"^^ex:authorityURL .
ex:library2 ex:formatterURL "https://id.loc.gov/authorities/2" .
```

You might also employ multiple tools when checking the well-formedness of the data: one for materializing the datatype (i.e. turning `"https://id.loc.gov/authorities/2"` to `"https://id.loc.gov/authorities/2"^^ex:authorityURL`) and one for ensuring that all literals are valid according to their datatype.

---

At first glance, SHACL seems to be more focused on validating properties of nodes rather than literals themselves:

```
ex:LibraryShape a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:targetClass ex:Library ;
  sh:property [
    sh:path ex:formatterURL ;
    sh:datatype ex:authorityURL ;
    sh:pattern "^https:\\/\\/id\\.loc\\.gov\\/authorities\\/."
  ] .
```

It seems reasonable to me to also produce the following shape for validating all literals, but I am not sure if that conforms to the SHACL specification:

```
ex:authorityURL a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:pattern "^https:\\/\\/id\\.loc\\.gov\\/authorities\\/." .
```

Since `ex:authorityURL` is a class, its instances should be validated according to the shape, so it depends on whether it can recognize that literals are instances of their datatype and apply the pattern to their value.

---

OWL can be also used to specify the restriction:

```
ex:authorityURL a rdfs:Datatype ;
  owl:onDatatype xsd:anyURI ;
  owl:withRestrictions ( [ xsd:pattern "https:\\/\\/id\\.loc\\.gov\\/authorities\\/.+" ] ) .
```

That makes the class consist of all literals restricted using the proper XML Schema facet. You might be able to define the restriction in pure XML as well, but I do not know how many tools support that.

---

So far there are 3 properties that can be used to describe a datatype. It depends on the tools which of them is the best, but there is nothing preventing you from using all of them. There are also slight differences in the patterns themselves (`schema:valuePattern` refers to HTML which uses the JavaScript specification, while `sh:pattern` refers to SPARQL which uses the XPath specification, built upon `xsd:pattern` but with things like `^` and `$` added).

I have only shown the examples for one particular datatype, but the process can be applied generally. There are also complex types like JSON (I was unfortunately unable to find a standardized datatype URI for that) where you will probably have not much luck making it self-describing (although SHACL does provide support for custom validators), but I presume there is only a handful of those.